# how can I add stylesheet in wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i am new in wordpress , i make my template in html and css in this format

```
root[folder]
  css[folder]
    style.css
  js[folder]
    script.js
index.html
```

I place it into theme directory and now what ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WP, you need to `enqueue` your scripts and styles

See the WP [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) for everything you need to get started

Example

`wp_enqueue_style('styleCSS', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). 'path/to/style.css');`

This will go in your `functions.php` located in the Theme.

If it's not working, check your path. A good help is the network tab in your browser, it will tell you if its 404 or 200.

Comment: thank you for help, can you tell me how to i begain learning wordpress ?

Comment: Best way is to visit the WP Codex and start reading from page one. Install WP and get it working, and then look at some of the Themes that come with it and by following the codex you will soon understand how it all fits together. 

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You have to `enqueue` stylessheets and js scripts to add to your theme. see below codes :

```
function my_theme_scripts(){

// Theme's main stylesheet ( style.css ).
wp_enqueue_style( 'twentysixteen-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

// custom theme's stylesheet like (font-awesome)
wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome-stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.css', array( '' ), '20170106' );

//add custom scripts to your theme
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/app.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20170106', true );
//adding jquery into array means its dependable to jquery
}
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts' ); //hooking/adding those scripts and stylesheets to wordpress
```

Lets say you want latest version [jquery][1] to your theme from google cdn. For this you have to first deregister installed jquery from wordpress.

```
// include custom jQuery
function include_custom_jquery() {

wp_deregister_script('jquery'); //removing installed jquery

wp_enqueue_script('jquery','https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, true); //adding custom jquery
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_custom_jquery' );
```

Comment: are the add_acction function for activate the stylesheet and script file function .???

Comment: yes , this function for activating those stylesheets and scripts view a details here [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)